# Visual Studio 2015 Deployment via SCCM 2012 R2

Tags: visual-studio, sccm-2012-r2

I'm looking to create a deployment for Visual Studio 2015 using SCCM 2012 R2. I'm an experienced SCCM Admin, so I'm pretty good on that territory, but I'm running in to a snag with Visual Studio itself.

I'm struggling with creating the XML Admin File. An excerpt from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225237.aspx) :

> To do this, you must first create the AdminDeployment.xml file by using the /CreateAdminFile   command-line parameter.

So I run CMD Prompt from the folder that contains my EXE for VS2015 and give the command a try. Here's my command I ran

```
vs_professional.exe /CreateAdminFile AdminDeployment.xml
```

And I also tried ...

```
vs_professional.exe /CreateAdminFile "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\VS2015 Test\AdminDeployment.xml"
```

After running either of these commands, I see a Visual Studio splash screen for about 30 seconds after which point nothing happens. I've spent a couple hours searching Google and here to see if I can find a hint as to why it might not be working, but have been unable to find any hints to resolving this. Any idea what I'm missing here?

PS: I've tried rebooting my computer and trying again to see if it helps. I've also tried from two PCs (Running Windows 10 Pro and Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is typical in life I have immediately found the answer after asking the question. Haha.

While I have no idea why the previous two iterations failed, I have found the correct way to run this.

```
vs_professional.exe /CreateAdminFile .\AdminDeployment.xml
```

This command correctly created the XML file on both machines.